# What should the FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion

The new Tor.SE is going to need an FAQ; this is a place for discussion about what it should contain.

Obviously it should contain a small list of what's on topic and what's off topic (might be a good thing to hammer down in another meta question); what else should be in there?

Answer (score 4):

**TOR vs Tor.**

Seeing as this seems to be one of the most common mistakes people make, I feel it deserves a place in the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rough outline of how the page should be and and some suggestions as to what it should contain.

---

Tor Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for researchers, developers, and users of Tor.

If you have a question about...

- Theoretical or practical aspects of Tor (design and implementation)
- Configuring and installing Tor for your setup (please check [Tor Project](https://www.torproject.org/) before asking)
- Problems while using Tor
- Getting involved with Tor (see [outreach](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outreach), [contributions](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contributions) and the [Tor Project website](https://www.torproject.org/))
- Privacy concerns
- Legal aspects of using Tor network

and it is not about...

- <Add off-topic points here>

...then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

---

Feel free to add, edit or remove any points. Do post a justification below this post as to why you think the change should be done. Try not to change the formatting style as this is what is generally followed across most sites.

Comment: I've updated the FAQ to contain some of these points. Please update if anyone thinks of others!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this section should be expanded from :

> Ask about...
>
> ```
> Specific issues with Tor
> Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered
> ```

**to :**

> Ask about...
>
> ```
> Specific issues with Tor
> Specific questions about Tor model and differences beetwen it and other anymousing netowrks (protocols)
> Privacy, when you're using Tor
> Legality of using Tor netowrk
> Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered
> ```